# How to save my styles theme on notepad++

Tags: notepad++

It took me an hour to style my theme on notepad++ now I have two problems. 1) how do I save my custom style theme every time I create a new file I want my style theme to intuitively apply colours to my tags in new file.
2) If I have to save my current file on notepad++ should I save it with .html extension or txt extension? I tried this but still I am loosing all the style formats.  Any idea how to do?

Thanks

Comment: If it is only css save it as .css . Otherwise use .html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys after saving I was able to open it in .html extn

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue using the latest version (5.8.5).
I believe a bug report is in order. Here is a bug that seems to (at the very least) be related: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2893679&group_id=95717&atid=612382

Another option (until the issue gets resolved) may be to manually add a theme to %PROGRAMFILES%\Notepad++\themes
(Note that you have to run your editor as Administrator to be able to save this file.)

Simply copy the theme you like, and edit the copy to your liking.
In your case, editing the fontName under  should do the trick.
Additionally you may want to edit name="stylerTheme" path="" in your %APPDATA%\Notepad++\config.xml file.